# Hololens device portal can't install package because a framework can't be found,miss framework Microsoft.VCLibs.140

Tags: hololens, windows-mixed-reality

I am deploying uwp app exported from visual studio 2019 using release and x86 config,the solution is exported from unity 2018.4.29 using il2cpp as script backend,the unity build setting is shown below:

[image: img_1]

when I successfully generate the appx package and try to install it through the device portal,I checked the checkbox and select the right package and x86 dependency generated by the visual studio, shown below:

[image: img_2]

after successfully upload it to hololens, I get this message:

[image: img_3]

Can anyone help for this strange issue?Is that a hololens system bug?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't link to external images

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.VCLibs 14.0 is usually located at the following path: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Kits\10\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.VCLibs\14.0`, you can select the appx file of VCLibs 14.0 as a necessary dependency in the second step of the installation.

Besides, We always recommend the latest Unity LTS (Long Term Support) stream as the best version to develop MR app, and the current recommendation is to use Unity 2019.4.15f1: https://unity3d.com/unity/qa/lts-releases

Comment: but the version of appx dependency in generated apppackage x86 folder is the same as the version of it in the path you've given.and in that path,I can only see 2 folder,debug and retail,but my config is release,I ve tried on hololens emulator and everything works fine.but once on device,I got this message.

Comment: As a test, could you install VCLibs separately first? Select Microsoft.VCLibs appx file`.\Appx\Retail\x86\Microsoft.VCLibs.x86.14.00.appx` and click Install directly. Do you see that it has been successfully registered? If it works, you then deploy your package to the device again. If not, please feedback on the behavior.